# PostgreSQL slow insert of a single row with RETURNING (taking 500ms in production)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-aurora

Bit stumped here. I have a small table called request_to_print. This is the table structure.

[image]

It has a single primary key of request_internal_id.

The table has 747 rows in it.

When an insert takes place, I've noticed it's taking 500ms+ which seems excessive. Most inserts are done in 1ms, and on far larger tables.

```
2020-10-06T10:38:29.284+11:00   Executed DbCommand (566ms) [Parameters=[@p0='', @p1='94ac21e6-bdd5-409c-90f6-4e014d1de763', @p2=NULL (DbType = DateTime), @p3='2020-10-05T23:38:28' (Nullable = true) (DbType = DateTime), @p4='E001'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
2020-10-06T10:38:29.284+11:00   INSERT INTO request_to_print (card_number, customer_internal_id, request_sent_date, requested_date, requesting_store)
2020-10-06T10:38:29.284+11:00   VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)
2020-10-06T10:38:29.284+11:00   RETURNING request_internal_id;
```

I have run this command in our test environment in similar conditions. Because it's an insert, there's not a lot of stuff to analyze/explain. I mean, it's just putting a row of data in. Here's what I got from tracing the insert:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "ModifyTable",
      "Operation": "Insert",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Relation Name": "request_to_print",
      "Schema": "public",
      "Alias": "request_to_print",
      "Startup Cost": 0,
      "Total Cost": 0.02,
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Plan Width": 304,
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.087,
      "Actual Total Time": 0.088,
      "Actual Rows": 1,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": [
        "request_internal_id"
      ],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 2,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "I/O Read Time": 0,
      "I/O Write Time": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Result",
          "Parent Relationship": "Member",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Total Cost": 0.02,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 304,
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.03,
          "Actual Total Time": 0.031,
          "Actual Rows": 1,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": [
            "uuid_generate_v4()",
            "'2705000000835'::character varying(100)",
            "'aaaaaaaa-d0c9-46bc-b83e-cec6a22d6e82'::uuid",
            "now()",
            "'E001'::character varying(10)",
            "NULL::timestamp without time zone"
          ],
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "I/O Read Time": 0,
          "I/O Write Time": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 0.03,
    "Triggers": [],
    "Execution Time": 0.107
  }
]
```

Can anyone assist as to why such a seemingly innocent insert on a small table is taking so long? For context, I am using Entity Framework Core 3.1 and a .NET Core application to perform the inserts (via the NPGSQL library).

Comment: Any indexes or foreign keys on the table? Is this insert happening inside a transaction of any sort? Can you replicate the slow insert through a psql connection to your prod DB, to rule out your client library?

Comment: What are the units for the time values in the trace? Have you tried on a  version of the table without `uuid_generate_v4()` as the default for the PK? I dimly remember reports of `uuid_generate_v4' being very slow under certain circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, no indexes or foreign keys on this table. Only the PK. The insert is happening inside a transaction as I believe EF Core wraps every database operation inside a transaction (even though it doesn't show up in the logs). I will investigate the suggestions made here - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The execution plan says that the operation was completed in 0.1ms; I guess that was not the slow execution.

Here are some ideas to investigate this:

- Use `auto_explain` to log the plans of slow executions. If you can afford the substantial overhead, set `auto_explain.analyze` and `auto_explain.buffers` to `on` so the plan tells you where the time was spent.
- Temporarily reduce `deadlock_timeout` to 0.1 and set `log_lock_waits` to `on`. Then you'll see in the log if the statement is blocked behind a lock.
- Use operating system tools to determine if the I/O system is totally overloaded.
- Read the log file for unusual nessages.

Comment: To clarify, the plan was done in a pre-production environment. I can't run the statements in production, at least not without some forethought. I will try executing the statement in production to get the query plan etc to see if it yields better insight than running it in the other environment. Thanks.